# Динамическое выделение памяти в си

Tags: c, указатели, память, структуры

Вопрос покажется, наверное, простым, но не для меня. Заранее неизвестен размер, всё зависит от желания пользователя. 
Объявление структуры:

```
struct Book* books;
```

Затем, если человек захочет, он может создать ещё 1 книгу, я выделяю память под него таким образом:

```
books = (struct Book*)malloc(sizeof(struct Book));
```

Но как я понял, я не добавляю в память ещё место, а только лишь отчищаю и выделяю новую память, поэтому могу иметь только 1 книгу в структуре. Как со временем добавлять в память место по мере добавления 1 книгой? Объявлять заранее сколько-то место не является оптимальным, так как не знаем, сколько нужно будет добавлять, всё решается в прайм-тайм.

Или всё решается объявлением struct Book** books?

Comment: Решил через struct Book** books, но хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение.

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл подумать об использовании связного списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для перераспределения памяти попробуйте использовать realloc().
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc

Answer (score 0):

Realloc использовать в этом случае не вариант, так как то, что он делает - это выделяет динамически большее место в памяти, затем копирует данные и предыдущего меньшего места, а затем очищает то меньшее место. Представь у тебя уже занят 1 Гбайт пямяти и ты делаешь realloc на 1 Гбайт + 1 байт. В этом случае тебе надо будет выделить заново 1 Гбайт + 1 байт, скопировать 1 Гбайт и очистить 1 Гбайт. Очень не производительно! 
В двоём случае надо реализовать абстрактный тип данных *список*, односвязный или двусвязный. Можень использовать готовые решения из многих библиотек (glib к примеру) или самому написать, включив операции создания списка, добавления элемента, удаления элемента и поиска элемента. Каждый элемен спмска будет в качестве данных содержать указатель на выделенную так-же динамически память под структуру книги с информацией о ней.

Comment: Не все так однозначно. Прежде всего, realloc в первую очередь пытается расширить уже выделенный фрагмент памяти, а если это не возможно, тогда выделяет новый и копирует. Никакой очистки ранее выделенного фрагмента   не производится, при освобождении он включатся в пул свободных (возможно объединяясь с предшествующим и последующим свободными фрагментами). Далее, надо понимать, что последовательный доступ к элементам массива быстрее, а сами элементы меньше, чем аналогичные элементы списка (на размер одного (или 2-х для двусвязного списка) указателей + возможный padding на выравнивание).

Comment: Массив позволяет прямой доступ по индексу, а список нет. При построении динамического массива правильной стратегией является запрос с учетом его роста (вызывая realloc, запрашиваем место не для одного, а для нескольких элементов).

Comment: Впрочем, все зависит от задачи. Для некоторых задач, особенно когда блок данных должен присутствовать одновременно в нескольких наборах данных, без списков не обойтись (если эти наборы хорошо определены, то включаем соответсвующие указатели на этапе определения структуры данных, в противном случае динамически строим списки из элементов, ссылающихся на данные в других контейнерах)

Comment: Всего лишь стоит увеличивать не "на", а "в", и проблема, по сути, решена...

Comment: @Harry, стандартные аллокаторы так и поступают. Обычно множитель колеблется от 1.5 до 2 (в некоторых аллокаторах, насколько помню,  он не константен)

Comment: Кстати, насколько помню, в python списки реализуются в виде динамических массивов указателей

Comment: @avp А я на это и намекал :)